# Mutex on Serial Port on linux bash script

Tags: file, shell, serial-port, mutex, tty

i'm using two scripts, one performs a write on a specified serial port, and the second script continuously reads from it.

I need to have mutex on this serial port, to assure that only one script is using the serial port a time.

```
Reading script:
./Read -p {myserialport} -v $2 -r $3 

Writing script:
./Write -p {myserialport} -v $2 -r $3 

I need to transform this into:

Reading script:
//GET mutex on {myserialport}
./Read -p {myserialport} -v $2 -r $3 
//RELEASE

Writing script:
//GET mutex on {myserialport}
./Write -p {myserialport} -v $2 -r $3 
//RELEASE
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice example using bash [here](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/mutex)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thank you for the advice - I didn't wish to take credit for something which was not my work, nor repeat material that is readily available elsewhere but if that is the way SO operates, I shall happily try to comply in future.

Comment: Attribution is plenty =)